# Create a custom compund buttons with divided circle shape

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view, custom-view, viewgroup

How would you go on implementing such a compound view :

[image]

note that it contains 2 buttons, A and B.

Comment: Just out of curiosity ? how big will this circle be ? because you have to consider that the touch space for the user will be really annoying.

Comment: it will be big enough, and i may provide spaces between the buttons, or produce some growing animation or some other solution if it gets annoying as you say it would. I will keep that in mind anyway. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'd go with 2 Buttons (or ImageViews or TextViews or ImageButtons, you name it). Each having a sector of the circle as its background. Both centered horizontally and the second one set to be **below** the first one.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to do this in a single view, then you could draw `filled path (arc)` for `A` and `B`. For touch detection, you might override the `onTouch` to know if the user tapped on `A` region or `B` region. You could expose this outside the view via an `Interface`. The advantage here is that you could easily dynamically change the `A` and `B` region. The partition can be easily modified.
2. But if you are not after dynamic change then you could simply have a linearLayout with vertical orientation and have two buttons with the background of a sector. (just like Frank N. Stein suggested in the comment)